# Django - Automatically filling user in form

Tags: django

I am trying to create a form in Django that when is submitted should save data in DB only for the registered user.

Basically, student field should be field in by default with the logged in user

The problem is that when I am submitting the form I get the following error message:
Cannot assign "< SimpleLazyObject: < User: 123 >> " :  "RegistrationRequest.student" must be a "Students" instance.

Models.py:

```
class Students(models.Model):
    Username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Group = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Username) + ' ' + self.FirstName +' ' + self.LastName

class RegistrationRequest(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + ' ' + str(self.title) + ' ' + str(self.description) + ' ' + str(self.teacher)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.CharField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()
    teacher = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationRequest
        exclude = ["student"]
```

views.py

```
def registrationRequest(request):
    form = RegistrationRequestForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            publish = form.save(commit=False)
            publish.student = request.user
            publish.save()

    return render(request, 'users/RegistrationRequest.html', {'form':form})
```

Can you please advise how to solve this problem
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`student` field in `RegistrationRequest` is foreign key to `Students` model, not `User`.

**Fix**:

```
user = request.user
try:
    student = Students.objects.get(Username=user)
except Students.DoesNotExist:
    # handle Student not found error here
    pass

publish.student = student
```